# How to get rid of unwanted things in Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a Yaml file containing all my api definition in `OpenAPI 3.0`.
My requirement is to load `Swagger UI` from my springboot application and I have used Springfox dependencies to do the same .

But "`basic error controller`" appears from nowhere in the UI.

> How to get rid of these unnecessary things in Swagger UI?

Below are the dependencies used .

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I expect all the things to be loaded from my Yaml file only but somethings are ignored from Yaml and somethings are added automatically by springfox.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGtNo.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Basic Error Controller In SpringFox SwaggerUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941917/remove-basic-error-controller-in-springfox-swaggerui), [Avoiding default basic-error-controller in Swagger API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33431454/113116)